# How to send buffer in a HTTP request

Tags: node.js, angular

Im using NodeJS/Angular.

I wanted to render a document using Carbone in NodeJS, and send the result in a http request.

Myfile.js:

```
router.get('/executeFusion/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Data to inject
    const data = {
      firstname: 'BLB',
      lastname: 'MAR'
    };

    carbone.render('./node_modules/carbone/examples/simple.odt', data, async function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});

const file = './result.odt';

res.download(file);

  }
  catch (err) {
    errorDbHandler.sendErrorHttp(err, res);
  }
});
```

MyComponent.ts:

```
this.fusionService.executeFusion()
.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}, 
           (error) => console.log(error));
```

MyService.ts :

```
export class FusionService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) { }

  executeFusion() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.configService.getUrlApi()}/api/Fusion/executeFusion/`);
  }
}
```

But the, I got this error:

[image]

The main idea here is, generating a document in NodeJS, send it to Angular in order to download it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to promise which is mentioned in the question:

```
this.fusionService.executeFusion().toPromise().then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        }).catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
```

But when you request the Http request in angular, you should use httpClient to make it and it returns the observable like this:

```
this.fusionService.executeFusion()
    .subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}, 
               (error) =>. console.log(error));
```

And, to make the express server send the file as a downloaded one:

```
  res.download(file);
```

```
xport class FusionService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) { }

  executeFusion() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.configService.getUrlApi()}/api/Fusion/executeFusion/`, {response: 'application/txt'}); // type should match the type you are sending from API
  }
}
```

for more details check [here](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res).

Comment: Still show the HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 201, statusText: "Created", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/Fusion/executeFusion/", ok: false, …} error, what did I miss here?

Comment: First test the API alone in postman. Change the `res.status(201).send(result);` to `res.download(file);`. Also, please add the angular code of the service and add the full error stack.

Comment: Have you checked the URL in browser, does it download the file? copy paste the URL in browser and check it.

Comment: No it doesnt, I think I should change strategy. In fact, why couldnt I send the (result) which is a buffer with an http request?

Comment: So there might be an issue with how you are sending the response.